# Default multiple labels with semantic UI react drop down

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I am using the semantic react dropdown and I am trying to get it so the options are already in the drop down as multiple labels but I cant seem to  add them as default values then I want to be able to add more which I think I can already do with this example but I am having problems with mainly have multiple default multiple label is there any one that can help

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Dropdown } from 'semantic-ui-react'

const options = [
  { key: 'English', text: 'English', value: 'English' },
  { key: 'French', text: 'French', value: 'French' },
  { key: 'Spanish', text: 'Spanish', value: 'Spanish' },
  { key: 'German', text: 'German', value: 'German' },
  { key: 'Chinese', text: 'Chinese', value: 'Chinese' },
]

class DropdownExampleAllowAdditions extends Component {
  state = { options }

  handleAddition = (e, { value }) => {
    console.log('assinf')
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      options: [{ text: value, value }, ...prevState.options],
    }))
  }


  handleChange = (e, { value }) =>{ console.log(value) 
    return this.setState({ currentValues: value })}

  render() {
    const { currentValues } = this.state

    return (
      <Dropdown
        options={this.state.options}
        placeholder='Choose Languages'
        search={(props)=>(props)}
        defaultSelectedLabel={ options}
        selection
        fluid
        multiple
        allowAdditions
        value={currentValues}
        onAddItem={this.handleAddition}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      />
    )
  }
}

export default DropdownExampleAllowAdditions
```

I keep on getting this value  when I try to add anything to the default label

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `defaultSelectedLabel` supplied to `Dropdown`, expected one of type [number, string].
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for you to have this working your `defaultSelectedLabel` should be of type either number or string. So, first of all, you should not send array there. Secondly, I believe that for what you want `defaultValue` props is made. It's definition in documentation is declared as: "Initial value or value array if multiple.". If you check my [codesendbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/twilight-framework-cf0h7y?file=/src/App.js), you'll see it working there.

```
defaultValue={["English", "French"]} // is what I did
```